# A basic square root inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to show that
$$\sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2} + \sqrt{(x_2 - y_2)^2} \equiv |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|$$
as part of some other proof (I used this result to follow tha tother proof in question). This feels like it should be a very basic statement but I can't quite see it. Can anyone provide a hint? It feels like a triangle inequality type thing but it's not quite (since the $x$ and $y$ are mixed up together). Maybe it's not even true and I've messed up understanding that other proof.

Comment: Square both sides

Comment: Oy, thank you @HagenvonEitzen